# Schengen boarding/entry without visa for final destination (non-Schengen)

Tags: visas, schengen, stopovers, denial-of-entry

I'm an Indian citizen with a valid Schengen short-stay visa.

I intend to travel on Emirates from New York to Dubai with a stopover of 3 days in Milan in between. I don't have the Dubai visa in hand yet, but should get it while I'm in Milan. My questions are:

1. Will I be asked for a valid Dubai visa while checking in at New York. I'm pretty sure this is a no, as they will only check me in for New York -> Milan, but just want to be sure.
2. Will I be asked for a valid Dubai visa or return/outbound ticket at immigration while entering Milan? Can I be denied entry if I cannot furnish one?

Comment: Why do you want to apply for that visa in Milan?

Comment: Are your two flights part of the same booking ? Regarding #2 I would think not, Italian authorities don't care if you leave Dubai, they'll only be checking the Schengen visa

Comment: No questions asked if you have a valid schengen visa in Milan. 96h dubai e-visa is possible only if you travel on emirates and you have a valid outward ticket to another destination. Please check with emirates!

Comment: @Relaxed: I won't be applying for the visa in Milan. Dubai tourist visas can be obtained by family members who are residents of Dubai directly from Dubai. My dad is in the process of applying for one for me and I predict that I'll receive it after processing only once I'm in Milan.

Comment: @Blackbird57: Yes, the two flights are on the same booking. Did you mean that the Italian authorities don't care if you leave "for" Dubai?

Comment: @FM Sounds like a reasonable explanation. As I explained in my answer, the important thing is to have a good explanation, beyond that you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a Schengen visa, I would not expect any problem in New York but it's really something you should take up with the airline.

In Milan, things are a bit different. There is obviously no requirement to have a Dubai visa when entering the Schengen area and it's most likely that the border guards won't ask anything about that. Even holding a ticket out of the area is not formally required. But they can more-or-less ask you about anything and everything to evaluate your intentions.

So they might very well ask how long you want to stay, then where you will go next and at this point inquire about the ticket or the visa. I would not expect most landing interviews to go that far into details but it's *possible* (Italy reports that [entry checks take 1 min on average](http://www.statewatch.org/news/2011/may/eu-council-tcn-exit-entry-recording-questionnaire-replies-8552-add2-09.pdf) for people with a visa like yourself, even less in other situations, which does not leave a lot of time for extensive questioning).

If it happens, having nothing to show could diminish your credibility and the notion that you could come without an onward ticket or a visa for your next destination or choose to waste time on all this during such a short visit might sound odd, so be prepared to explain why you are doing it that way. Or just do it before leaving New York to have some additional peace of mind.

In any case, they would refuse entry because they don't believe you and rule that the purpose of your stay and/or your intent to leave the Schengen area could not ascertained, not merely because you have no Dubai visa *per se*.

Comment: Just to clarify, I already have an outward ticket and I will not be spending any time in Milan applying for a Dubai visa. My family is applying for my Dubai visa directly in Dubai.

Comment: @FM That's certainly better, my guess is that if you have a ticket they won't even ask about the visa and if they do, there is no reason your explanation should not satisfy them. But obviously I can't predict exactly what will happen.